# access $_GET value after form submission

Tags: php, forms

example.php gets value of x by $_GET['x'] from another page.

I have a form in the same page (example.php). Upon submission of the form, I am loosing the value of x.

My question is: How can I keep and access the value of x after submission of the form.

Code is like this:

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['y'])) {
    $y = $_GET['y']; // I have also tried with $_REQUEST    
}

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $x = $_POST['field1'];
    echo $y."<br>";
    echo $x;
}

?>

<form name="form1" action="example.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Echo the name" />
</form>
</body
```

I have also tried the following as per suggestion, but its not working:

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $x = $_POST['field1'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    echo $y."<br>";
    echo $x;
}
?>

<form name="form1" action="dollar_get_and_form1.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?php htmlentities($_GET['y']) ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Echo the name" />
</form>
</body>
```

Issue is solved by the following codes:

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['x'])) {
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    echo $x;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['xValue'].'<br>'; 
    echo $_POST['y'];
}    
?>    
<form name="form1" action="example.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="y" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Echo the name" />
    <input type="hidden" id="xValue" name="xValue" value="<?php echo $x; ?>"/>
</form>    
</body>
```

Thanks to all for your suggestions. If there are better ways to do this, please suggest so.

Comment: Your problem is `y` doesn't exist

Comment: try to save the value of your get in a session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is POST not GET so the variable will be gone. The best way to get the desired result is through a hidden form field:

`<input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?=htmlentities($_GET['y'])?>" />`

Then it will be available as `$_POST['y']` when the user submits the form

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. But its not working. Please see details in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

your form's **method** is **post** so, there is not `$_GET`, and `$_GET` don't work here...
where is `$_GET['y']` comming from?

Comment: That's not correct, `<form method="POST" action="example.php?y=SomeValue">` will be a POST request type, but `$_GET['y']` will have the value "SomeValue". $_GET & $_POST are not mutually exclusive (though I can see why it seems that they would be)

Comment: I see, I misread your comment `$_GET` don't work here as saying `$_GET` is not present because the form is `$_POST`.

Comment: @Kiyarash: $_GET('y') is coming from another script.

Comment: @Kiyarash: Value of y is coming from another script. Value of x is coming from the form inside example.php. How can I access that value (y) after form submission?

Comment: Your two forms submit with one button or two?
if both f them came from one button, it's easy, but if they have separate buttons, store the value of $_GET['y'] in session...

Answer (score 0):

As HTTP is stateless protocol, Get/Post value persistence is limited to last page and current page. You have to make you use of one of techniques : 
"hidden field","session" ,"cookie" or writing/reading to tmp. file  to preserve value/state.

Answer (score -1):

use get instead of post method='get'; and create a field(hidden) y like following

---

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['y'])) {
    $y = $_GET['y']; // I have also tried with $_REQUEST    
}

if($_GET['submit']) {
    $x = $_GET['field1'];
    echo $y."<br>";
    echo $x;
}

?>

<form name="form1" action="example.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="y" value=1 />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Echo the name" />
</form>
</body
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the example.php gets the value of y from another page. The value of x comes from the form inside the example.php.